# How do I solve max min (x − y) and min max (x − y) such that y≥0 and x≥0?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

solve max min (x − y) and min max (x − y) such that y≥0 and x≥0

[image]

I don't have a clue where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the inside and work your way out.  $$\min_{y\ge 0} x-y$$ is a function of $x$.  However, regardless of what $x$ is, the minimum is $-\infty$ as $y$ may be arbitrarily large.  Hence, $$\max_{x\ge 0}\min_{y\ge 0}x-y=\max_{x\ge 0} -\infty$$
which is just $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about setting y to infinity at first, but taking the max of infinity seemed weird so I wasn't sure if it was correct.

Comment: Usually mathematicians don't like taking $\max$ or $\min$ to be $\pm \infty$, reserving $\sup$ and $\inf$; but I find in LP notation is somewhat different.